# Create a 2D numpy array of one-hot vectors from a 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, data-processing

I have a 1D numpy array, let's call it *labels*. Each element of this array is a digit (0...9). I want to transform *labels* array into a 2D numpy array of zeros, let's call it *y_train*. The new 2D array is such that for the element *labels[i]*, the i<sup>th</sup> row of *y_train*, has exactly one element at index  *label[i]* equal to 1.0  . One way this could be done is by iterating over the *labels* array. See below

```
>>> labels = [1, 5, 3, 9, 4]
>>> y_train = np.zeros((5, 10))
>>> for i in range(len(labels)):
        y_train[i][labels[i]] = 1.0
>>> y_train
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

This code snippet depicts what I am tryingto achieve.
So, my main question is how can I vectorize this operation for faster computation using numpy ?

Comment: Although I suspect is not too hard to do this, there is one hot encoding functions for Keras and Scipy (in case that also works for you).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this in place of the loop:

```
y_train[np.arange(len(labels)), labels] = 1
```

But I recommend using available library methods in sklearn or other packages.

Comment: What if the shape of y_train was  (5, 1, 10) ? Then how will we edit the code?

Comment: You can do this `y_train[np.arange(len(labels)), :, labels] = 1`. Just add a `:` in that dimension. Since it's a single dimension, `0` also works in place of `:`. If you need something more general, may be you should edit the question by adding more details.

Comment: If you are not familiar with this kind of indexing, you can take a look [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).